# How to check requested port number in Apache Configuration

Tags: apache-httpd

I am using Apache 2.2. Now in that, I have done some changes: if any request on my port I want to send back http status code 404.

Now I have 3 ports running on my Apache Server: `8808,8809,8810`.
If the request comes on the third port I want to send back to the user `404 http status code`.

Currently I have this in my `httpd.conf`

```
RedirectMatch 404 ".*"
ErrorDocument 404 "Not Found"
```

Now how can I do this for a specific port, if the request comes in to that port?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work with a virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:8808>
    RedirectMatch 404 ".*"
    ErrorDocument 404 "Not Found"
</VirtualHost>
```

repeat that for other ports, obviously.

Note that if you've already got a `<VirtualHost *:*>` or something in your apache configuration, you will need to change that -- otherwise it will be valid for this port as well, and you'll have overlapping virtual hosts (which will almost certainly not do what you want).

Comment: this is my url on which i am getting request https://abc.com:8808/ota/test.pl

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtualhost for all your ports:

```
<VirtualHost *:8808>
    some directives here
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8809>
    some directives there
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8810>
    RedirectMatch 404 ".*"
    ErrorDocument 404 "Not Found"
</VirtualHost>
```

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/lamp-package-setup.html) for more relevant info, it may help too.